# Calling hide method of Fl_Double_Window has no effect in a multi-thread FLTK C++ application (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c++, multithreading, widget, window, fltk

I'm working on a C++ FLTK application. This is a multi-thread application that creates & shows a modal window in a thread using below code:

```
Fl_Double_Window* dlg = new Fl_Double_Window(0, 0, 200, 100);
...
dlg->set_modal();
Fl::visual(FL_DOUBLE|FL_INDEX);
dlg->show();
```

then in same thread I create a new thread & pass pointer to `Fl_Double_Window` object to it as thread parameter:

```
CreateThread(
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        &beginProgress,     // thread function name
        (LPVOID) dlg,       // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        NULL);
```

& in my thread function I do some operations & then I need to hide the showing modal window:

```
DWORD WINAPI beginProgress(LPVOID args)
{
    //do some operations
    ((Fl_Double_Window*)args)->hide();
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is here that my code executes successfully with no error, but after executing `hide` method of `dlg` object pointer, window does NOT hides & seem calling `hide` or even deleting window object using `delete dlg` has no effect.
I guess this problem is related to multi-threading behavior, but I can't guess what cause the problem & how should I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [FLTK guide on multithreading](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/advanced.html):

> FLTK supports multiple platforms, some of them which do not allow any
>   other but the main thread to handle system events and open or close
>   windows. The safe thing to do is to adhere to the following rules for
>   threads on all operating systems:
>
> - **Don't `show()` or `hide()` anything that contains widgets derived from Fl_Window, including dialogs, file choosers, subwindows or `Fl_GL_Windows`**

Here is the FLTK-recommended way to handle [GUI updates from a background thread](http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/Threads_8h.html):

> The only
>   workaround is to store what you want to do in static variables, call
>   `fltk::awake()`, and make the main thread call `fltk::wait()` repeatedly,
>   checking and acting on the static values after each call.